# Mercurial: How to clone using SSH and .ppk file?

Tags: ssh, mercurial, putty, private-key

```
hg clone ssh://denis@medsecop.com//var/www/vhosts/medsecop.com/stage/symphony
```

returns

```
remote: Permission denied (publickey).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I have the `.ppk` file but I don't know how to add options to the `ssh` command above to use (it says "hg clone doesn't take more arguments")

```
 -i /path/to/keys.ppk
```

I connect to SSH with this:

```
sudo ssh -v denis@medsecop.com -i /home/denis/Desktop/MedSec/my-openssh-key
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have replaced all the instances of `.pkk`, with `.ppk` (it's Putty Private Key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the public key

```
ssh-add file.ppk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tag question with putty tag, I suppose, you use Windows at your side (and some Win-specific details I'll mention later)?

> I don't know how to add options to the ssh command above to use

Well, for any ssh-powered repositories you **must** to define used ssh-client in (global, user- or repository-specific) config file. For key-based authorization you can define private-key file as parameter of used command or use special additional tool (ssh-agent in *Nix or pageant in Win or...)

**Sample**

Windows-box with Mercurial (TortoiseHG), full Putty, without Cygwin

Key-based authorization for ssh-repositories: Plink + Pageant

Global mercurial.ini part

```
[ui]
merge = ...
username = ...
ssh = "PATH\TO\TortoisePlink.exe"
```

Also Pageant is running and (putty-type) private keys for published public keys loaded into it

When I connect to any ssh-repo, authorization happens automagically

Pageant-less version may include

- `-i KEYFILE` option for TortoisePlink at the repository level - in the .hg\hgrc
- `--load SESSION` option for TortoisePlink (same location as above) for using previously created Putty's session, which have all needed authorization predefined